# SELECT data with primary keys from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many, junction-table

I have a '*users*' table, an '*offers*' table, and a junction '*users_offers*' with userIDs and offerIDs.

How to select every offer from offers that belongs to a particular user?

I could achieve a solution (below) that actually starts select data from the junction table, then simply joins the offer columns, but the result is containing the junction columns as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_offers INNER JOIN offers ON users_offers.offerID = offers.ID 
WHERE userID = 1
```

Is there any solution that starts selection with offers?

Comment: Instead of selecting *, select just the columns you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SQL Alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM users_offers AS uo
INNER JOIN offers AS o ON uo.offerID = o.ID 
WHERE uo.userID = 1
```

Explanation:

`FROM users_offers AS uo` sets a new alias called "uo" pointing to the [users_offers] table. The same happens for `offers AS o`. These alias can be used in the other parts of your SQL statement.

Comment: Whoa, thanks. Actually I could omit users_offers alias, only 'o' seems enough.

Comment: Yes, you can, but I usually set alias for all tables used to make future changes easier. But that's a matter of taste.

Comment: I'm just in the early phase of complexity, so considerations like this feels overheads to me for now. Thanks again, spared me hours of Googling. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT offers_alias.*
FROM users_offers
INNER JOIN offers AS offers_alias ON users_offers.offerID = offers_alias.ID 
WHERE users_offers.userID = 1
```